# Can't save or edit entity with Symfony 2 app after dropping table column in database

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a Symfony 2 front end to a MySQL database. I changed my database by dropping a column on one of my tables. Within the app I have done the following to reflect this change:

- removed the field from the form class
- removed the field, getter & setter and annotations from the entity class
- removed the field from the templates

All the pages display correctly, but when I submit after editing or creating a new record, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'trial_abbrev' in 'NEW'
>   500 Internal Server Error - PDOException

I guess I must have missed something, but I suspect it is in the depths of the Doctrine magic stuff that happens automatically.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I'm working with the app_dev, so I didn't think that was necessary - but I'll give it a try

Comment: did you ran again doctrine:generate:entities --force?

Comment: Clearing cache didn't work-what does this actually do? After running php app/console cache:clear my app/cache folders were still full. Can I just manually delete everything from the folder?

Comment: @DonCallisto I only changed one column in one table - is there a way to run that command so it only re-generates a single entity?

Comment: it re-generates only entities that had a change. I'll try it myself in the recent past.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have any yml or xml files generated for doctrine?

Comment: @Jishnu G Nair There is a yml file in /Resources/config/doctring/metadata/orm, but I also removed the column from there.

Comment: @JishnuGNair i'm sure that i've delete (add) a field in an entity class, run again that command and had that field "persisted" to db.

Comment: Run which command? generate entities? Isn't the command you need to update the DB app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql (to see the sql it will run) and app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql (to update the db)?

Comment: if you are using an editor such as netbeans then you can search the whole project for occurrence of "trial_abbrev".

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but the comments to the question got confusing and somewhat disjointed.  So back to basics.  Run:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

It should say:

```
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

Please indicate what response you get and we can work from there.